# CSS-only drop-down menu items showing through

Tags: css

I'm trying to get a CSS-only drop-down menu working. It largely does work except for the fact that other content appears to be showing through and I can't work out why.

http://jsfiddle.net/uQveP/4/

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? CSS not my strong suit.

[image]

The drop-down is appearing in the correct position, but you can see the other "test" links showing through. In the image, the bottom two "test" links should be hidden by the presence of the dropdown.

TIA

Comment: What browser/version are you using? Can you post an image to let us know what it looks like, in the fiddle you gave I see nothing that screams out "This is the wrong behavior that I do not want".

Comment: http://puu.sh/ZuJ9. Same behaviour in current versions of IE, Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(2nd attempt)

Ok, if I understand correctly all you need to do is [move the z-index to the ULs](http://jsfiddle.net/uQveP/12/):

```
.drop-menu-header ul, .drop-menu-content ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}

.drop-menu-header ul li, .drop-menu-content ul li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  /*POOF*/
}

.drop-menu-header ul li ul, .drop-menu-content ul li ul {
  display: none;
  right: 0;
  /*SHAZAAM!*/
  z-index: 5;
}

.drop-menu-header ul li a {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #fff;
}

.drop-menu-content ul li a {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.drop-menu-header ul li a img.fake-button, .drop-menu-content ul li a img.fake-button {
  padding: 0;
}

.drop-menu-header ul ul li a, .drop-menu-content ul ul li a {
  padding: 5px 15px;
}

.drop-menu-header span {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #fff;
}

.drop-menu-content span {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.drop-menu-header ul li span a, .drop-menu-content ul li span a {
  padding: 0;
  display: inline;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.drop-menu-header li:hover ul, .drop-menu-content li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
}

.drop-menu-header li:hover li {
  float: none;
  background-color: #5c87b2;
}

.drop-menu-content li:hover li {
  float: none;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I didn't explain well enough, sorry. My original drop-downs were appearing in the right place, it's just the text from the ones underneath it were showing through the drop-down. I've clarified the question.

Comment: Updated to reflect better understanding of problem.

Comment: Gah, how did I miss that! Thank you very much.